# Ogr AddPointZM does not work. Cannot create any geometry with ZM values

Tags: gdal, ogr

I am trying to create LineStringZM using ogr java bindings. My code is below:

```
  private Geometry prepareLineString(Layer ly) {
    var result = new Geometry(ogr.wkbLineStringZM);
    for (int i = 0; i < ly.GetFeatureCount(); i++) {
        var feat = ly.GetFeature(i);
        var geom = feat.GetGeometryRef();
        var time = feat.GetFieldAsISO8601DateTime("time");
        result.AddPointZM(geom.GetX(), feat.GetGeometryRef().GetY(),
                feat.GetFieldAsDouble("ele"), Double.valueOf("21.37"));
    }
    return result;
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to create 4D geometry using ogr. I am using the
https://gdal.org/java/org/gdal/ogr/package-summary.html library